# Java adding issue

Tags: java

I have an issue with my java program displaying every number it is adding, what can I do so that it only displays the total. I am guessing since I have "element" in the last part of the code it showing every single addition: Here is what I have written:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int ans = 0;
        int num;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many integers do you have? (Max 20)");
        int x= keyboard.nextInt();


        int [] element = new int[x];

        for(int subscript = 0; subscript < element.length; subscript++){
            System.out.println("Enter element for subscript " + (subscript));
            element[subscript] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Here are all of those numbers");

        for(int subscript = 0; subscript < element.length; subscript++){

            num = element[subscript];
            System.out.println(num);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
            ans += element[i];
            System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + ans);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you're getting and what you expect to get instead.

Comment: //previous code for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
            ans += element[i];
            
        }System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + ans);//Later code

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//previous lines of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
    ans += element[i];
}
System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + ans);
```

//code follows

Answer (score 1):

Because You print out the 'num' as many as length of element. You have to delete that line if your intention is to show only the summed ans which is result of sumation. If you wanna show inputs then its fine

Also

Take this sentence out of the for loop

```
System.out.println("The sum of these numbers is " + ans);
```

Everytime for loops working, that line works too. So make it works once after you add all the numbers with for loop.